# Ошибки при запуске эмулятора в Android studio, можно ли с этим жить?

Tags: android, android-studio, linux-mint

После запуска эмулятора в android studio в event log все время вылетает две строки красновго цвета:

1. Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.

2.Emulator: E0804 17:09:24.871470530     837 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1596550164.871439071","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

После чего приложение запускается и работает как должно
ОС linux mint
Что это может быть и как от этого избавится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После поиска ответа на первую ошибку, нашел такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059822/android-emulator-failed-to-create-vulkan-instance):

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

дальше перезагрузить пк нужно будет. И [вот возможное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839898/android-emulator-gives-an-error-so-reuseport-and-debugging-not-working) второй ошибки. Но в целом если его работа вас устраивает можно ничего не менять)